# python regex dynamic string as input

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to get the string dynamically and use regex over it but i get the error:

coding partial snippet:

```
import re
def file_save():
    f = th1.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    re.search(r"<[^>]*\bname='([^']*)", f).group(1)       
    f.close()
```

Error

```
    re.search(r"<[^>]*\bname='([^']*)", f).group(1)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 166, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Here,the input string  has to be attained from a 'filename to be saved' which produces the text 'f' as:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Python34/abcd.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
```

the regex works perfect,but icannot get the string and get the ouput as:

```
C:/Python34/abcd.txt
```

Please help me to fix my problem.Answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using wrong tool.

If you want to get filename, just use `asksaveasfilename` instead of `asksaveasfile`.

```
def file_save():
    filename = th1.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt")
    # do something with the filename
```

Or, if you need to operate on the file, use `asksaveasfile` and use `name` attribute of the file returned.

```
def file_save():
    f = th1.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
    filename = f.name
    # do something with the filename
    f.close()
```

Comment: but,how do i get the input for the regex from filename saved?

Comment: @user3914506, What do you mean? You don't need to use regular expression to get filename.

Comment: then how could I get my Filename stored and save in a variable say x?

Comment: @user3914506, I updated the answer. Please check it out.